# Data in Android

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, file, constants

I have an Android app that contains a RecyclerView. The RecyclerView will not change, will have always same 10 elements so I was thinking that making a public static final array of Strings that contains elements names will be the best way for performance.
But on each element touch a new activity with a TextView (large text) will start. So, for each RecyclerView element will be 3 possible large text (random selected onClick event), that means a total of 30 large texts. This texts will never change.
What is best practice to save this texts?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing mate. If your just gonna have a String, why not simply keep it in `strings.xml`? Or just do it as final in the activity if it's not going to be used by any other resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF it's only around that amount of items AND there's no requirement to translate them, then I'd probably just keep them as a `String[]` in code.

A better way, which makes it easier to translate is to define the strings in `values/arrays.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <string-array name="numbers">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

and read them like this:

```
String [] arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers);
```